# Windows Phone 8 Just Prevent Map Control to Scrolling

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new in windows phone 8 development. I have a map containing the layer where I can dragging the line from one point to another, but the problem arise is whenever I am going to draw line over map the whole map is moving.

How should I stop just the map scrolling with out make disable the other user interaction features of map control?

Answer (score 1):

Set one of these properties to false, whitchever suits You best:

[image: Props]